# Extra long braces with \begin{array}[t]

Tags: equations, arrays, braces

the following is a snippet of a lecture note I am typing.

```
\[ \mathscr F=\left\{\{B_{\a}\}_{\a\in J}: \begin{array}[t]{rl}
            i)  &   B_{\a} \text{ are open}\\
            ii) &   \{B_{\a}\} \text{ is finitely inadequate}\\
            iii)&   I \subset J \text{ and } A_{\a}=B_{\a} \text{ whenever } \a\in I
        \end{array}\right\} \]
```

where `\a` is a macro for `\alpha`. This is producing the following output.

[image]

How to curb those extra-long top ends of the braces?

Comment: please always post complete document's not just fragments

Comment: why have you got `[t]` here? simply removing it would give better layout and more reasonable {}

Comment: Actually I want to start the first line of the array in the same line with `\{B\}_{\a}`

Comment: you could just have put that in the array in a new first column, incidentally you are using math italic for the i,ii,ii numbering which looks very weird. I'd use `\text{ii)}` if you can't use an `enumerate` enviornment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two alternatives to your current setup:

1. Put the construction inside another `array`.
2. Use `cases` instead and a different layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathscr F = \left\{
    \begin{array}{@{} l @{}}
      \{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}:
        \begin{array}[t]{r @{~} l}
          \textit{i})   &  B_{\alpha} \text{ are open}\\
          \textit{ii})  &  \{B_{\alpha}\} \text{ is finitely inadequate}\\
          \textit{iii}) &  I \subset J \text{ and } A_{\alpha}=B_{\alpha} \text{ whenever } \alpha\in I
        \end{array}
    \end{array}
  \right\}
\]

\[
  \mathscr F =
    \{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}:
    \begin{cases}
      \textit{i})   &  B_{\alpha} \text{ are open}\\
      \textit{ii})  &  \{B_{\alpha}\} \text{ is finitely inadequate}\\
      \textit{iii}) &  I \subset J \text{ and } A_{\alpha}=B_{\alpha} \text{ whenever } \alpha\in I
    \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please enlighten me what role do `@{}` and `@{~}` play here?

Comment: both of these break the top alignment, the first is essentially identical to simply leaving the `[t]` off the array in the question. (although actually lowering the braces wiile preserving teh top alignment (with delarray) would look weird, I don't think I'll post that answer:-)

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: `@{}` as part of the column specification removes the column separation. `@{~}` removes the column separation and inserts a tie `~` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I propose two other variants, built upon  `Bmatrix` , `\parbox` and an *inline* enumerate environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathscr F =
    \begin{Bmatrix}
      \{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}:\:
        \parbox{75mm}{%
        \begin{enumerate*}[label =$ \roman*) $, itemjoin ={; \enspace}]
          \item $ B_{\alpha} $ are open
          \item $ \{B_{\alpha}\} $ is finitely inadequate
          \item$ I \subset J $ and $ A_{\alpha}=B_{\alpha} $ whenever $ \alpha\in I $.
        \end{enumerate*}}
    \end{Bmatrix}
 \]

\[
  \mathscr F =
    \begin{Bmatrix}
      \{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}:\;
        \parbox[t]{75mm}{%
        \begin{enumerate*}[label =$ \roman*) $, itemjoin ={; \enspace}]
          \item $ B_{\alpha} $ are open
          \item $ \{B_{\alpha}\} $ is finitely inadequate
          \item$ I \subset J $ and $ A_{\alpha}=B_{\alpha} $ whenever $\alpha\in I$.
        \end{enumerate*}}
    \end{Bmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ooh an inline list, not sure I would have thought of that, I quite like the second one (+1) (not so sure about the first)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the first version, for me, would be nicer with a vertical rule.